# Why is my original array being altered after using Array.find?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of users.

I fetch a user and make a change to that user.

After I make the change to the user, why is the change reflected in the users array? I expect the change to only be reflected in the individual user.

```js
const users = [
  {'name': 'john'},
  {'name': 'blane'},
]

// fetch a user
const john = users.find(user => user.name === 'john');

// add new property to user
john.email = 'john@email.com';

console.log(users);

// expected output:
// {'name': 'john'},
// {'name': 'blane'},

// output
// {'name': 'john', email = 'john@email.com'},
// {'name': 'blane'},
```

Comment: Only one `john` object exists in memory. The `.find` does not clone the object - it just returns the existing object, which also exists in the array. Mutate that object, and you'll see the mutation when examining the object itself, or the array container it also happens to be in.

Comment: To clarify, the variable john is pointing to the object with the name of "john" in the array?

Comment: Yes - `john === users[0]`